# How can I detect Cocoa Emacs in my .emacs file?

Tags: cocoa, emacs, configuration, dot-emacs

How can I tell (from inside of .emacs) whether or not the Emacs version is Cocoa?  I only want some configuration options to apply when they are loaded in Cocoa Emacs and not in the command-line version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `(featurep 'ns)` to check for the NextStep emacs feature.  See also `C-h v window-system`, can check if that variable is `'ns`.

Comment: It looks like the system-type variable equals "darwin" for Cocoa Emacs versions.  How can I check for that value in .emacs?  I'm not very good with Emacs Lisp.

Comment: It looks like the first one contains the text "darwin" for cocoa emacs versions.  Actually, the second one has a symbol value of darwin, not a string value like I thought.

Answer (score 1):

It's sufficient to do something similar to the following:

To see if you're on a Mac and not running in the command-line version:

```
(when (and (eq system-type 'darwin) window-system)
  (setq my-option "cocoa"))
```

To see if you're on a Mac and are running in the command-line version:

```
(when (and (eq system-type 'darwin) (not window-system))
  (setq my-option "command-line"))
```

EDIT: I edited my answer to check for both Mac (system-type) and not command-line (window-system).

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to work, but maybe I should give it another shot.

Comment: I edited my answer so that it checked both criteria. See if that does the job for you.